# Discrete, high dimensional optimization techniques

Tags: optimization, bayesian-optimization, discrete-optimization

Suppose we have a binary vector of length 1000 where we can switch each element on or off. Each of the $2^{1000}$  different settings reveals a reward. The goal is to find the setting with the maximum reward in a finite amount of time.

Obviously, a random search will be completely useless because the space to be explored is simply too large. Are there optimization techniques (Bayesian or non-Bayesian) that show good empirical performance in these types of problems? I'd appreciate if someone could point me into the direction of some literature.

Comment: Do you have some form of "continuity" or other information on the landscape? If there is no form of correlation between neighbors you will effectively be doing random search, I believe. Some concrete context will help ... If out of luck here we can migrate to  https://or.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Very good point, sorry for not elaborating further on that. We can assume that similar settings have similar rewards. I.e., the change in rewards will only be small when changing one element of the vector.

Comment: That is, we could use a greedy algorithm where we change one element randomly and then choose the setting that maximizes the reward. Rinse and repeat and we should reach a (local) optimum. I'm just wondering whether there are better approaches to reach a (global) optimum.

Comment: In addition to the answer by @Tim, maybe simulated annealing, which in reality makes a random walk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that instantly comes to mind are [genetic algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) (see [genetic-algorithms](/questions/tagged/genetic-algorithms)) since operations such as mutations and cross-overs are trivial to do for bits (logical NOT, AND, OR, XOR operations). They do not have to be the fastest, but they have the advantage of quite efficiently exploring the solutions landscape (so are slightly biased towards exploration in exploration vs exploitation). Genetic algorithms are known to work with this kind of problems, though I do not have much experience with this kind of optimization problems, so I won't claim that this is the best possible approach.